# Как проверить существование поля в таблице MySQL базы данных?

Tags: php, mysql

Существует таблица my_category, как проверить в ней существование категории, чтобы не пытаться по новой добавить уже существующую?

```
$id = 'test';

$db->query( "SELECT * FROM my_category WHERE alt_name='$id'" );

while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) {
    
$cat_info[$row['alt_name']] = array ();

....

}
```

Как выполнить проверку, чтобы вновь не добавить категорию **test**?

UPD: пробую так выполнить проверку:

```
$res = $db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `my_category` LIKE '$id'"); // SHOW COLUMNS FROM `my_category` LIKE 'test'

//$var_dump($res); // object(mysqli_result)#7 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(6) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

$exists = mysqli_num_rows($res);

//$var_dump($exists); // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in - $var_dump($exists);

if (!$exists) {
    echo "<h1>Поле $id существует</h1>" . '<br>';
}else{
    echo "Поле $id не существует" . '<br>';
}
```

Должно работать, но не работает   :(

Comment: _Как выполнить проверку, чтобы вновь не добавить категорию test?_ добавить unique index для alt_name и ничего проверять не надо

Comment: Спасибо! Думал об этом, а ошибки появляться не будут при попытке добавить?

Comment: Будут, их надо будет ловить и ничего не делать.

Comment: Наверное INSERT IGNORE нужно использовать в таком случае, верно?

Comment: *INSERT **IGNORE*** конвертирует ошибку дублирования в предупреждение.